# How to get IEnumerable list values?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I've an IEnumerable list named list. It keeps these sample values:

[image]

I want to access **and assign to any variables** these Count, Start and End values, whenever I want. How can I do this?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You *can* access the values whenever you want by reading them from the objects.

Comment: And what is your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: Wouldn't `list[i].Count`/`list[i].Start`/`list[i].End` work???

Comment: With LINQ you can visit this list and map them to a new class where you can access from anywhere. After that, you just need to call ToList() on that IEnumerable.

Comment: I tried this:

foreach (var v in list) // also list[i]
{
    cnt= v.Count;
    strt= v.Start;
    nd = v.End;
}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `IEnumerable` itself doesn't have `Count`, `Start`, or `End`.  It's *elements* do, so you'll need to identify the element in the collection from which you want to read those values.  For example, to read the values on the first element:

```
var firstCount = list.First().Count;
var firstStart = list.First().Start;
var firstEnd = list.First().End;
```

Or if you want to get a collection of *all* the `Count` values, something like this:

```
var allCounts = list.Select(c => c.Count);
```

You're operating on a collection of elements, not a single element.  So to get information from any particular element you first need to identify it from the collection.  And there are [*lots* of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) you can chain together to identify any given element or set of elements.

Comment: @team16sah: Be aware that some of these methods will throw exceptions under certain conditions.  For example, `First()` will throw an exception if the collection is empty.  It's worth tinkering with all of the `IEnumerable<T>` extensions available to you and seeing how they behave.  Chaining them together provides a fairly powerful language for querying collections.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `loop` ?

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
   var count = item.Count;
}
```

Or use `ToList` and convert it to `List<T>` then you can access your value with index:

```
var myList = list.ToList();
var count = myList[0].Count;
```

Also if you know the type you can cast your `IEnumerable` to `IList<T>` in order to use indexer.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to access the list with `Linq` using the namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

like so

```
var firstListElement = list.ElementAt(0);
var firstListElementCount = firstListElement.Count;
// do more stuff with my first element of the list
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
list.Count()
list.First() or list.FirstOrDefault()
list.Last() or list.LastOrDefault()
```